# LINQ - Contains in?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to search in a Collection (which inherit an another Collection) for a property value.

```
private ObservableCollection<User> userCollection = someData;

public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Department> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//I can't use "Contains", because it requires an object of type "Department", but I don't have the object, just the string "Name" (in this case "MyDepartment")
var result = from usr in userCollection where (usr.Memberships.Contains("MyDepartment")) select usr;
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) to achieve what you want.

For example :

```
(from usr in userCollection select usr).
               Any(x=>x.Username.Contains("MyDepartment"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.Any()` on `IEnumerable` to achive what you want. This will return `true` if there are one or more elements in the collection where the predicate returns `true`.

```
var result = from usr in userCollection 
             where usr.Memberships.Any(m => m.Name == "MyDepartment")
             select usr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code example - you need to select the equivalent part of department you are checking against into a new collection which you then run Contains against.

```
var result = from usr in userCollection where (usr.Memberships.Select(m=>m.Name).Contains("MyDepartment")) select usr;
```

Alternatively - `IEnumerable.Any` is a better construct here than `Contains` - see other answers